# Convert specific row to Date in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert specific row value to date in R

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B"), b = c(19080, "df"))
```

Expected output : 19080 is a date actually

```
asd
  a     b
1 A "2022-03-29"
2 B    df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.Date`. Since a column cannot contain a Date and a character objects, you can convert your Date object to `as.character`.

```r
data.frame(a = c("A", "B"), b = c(as.character(as.Date(19080, origin = "1970-01-01")), "df"))

  a          b
1 A 2022-03-29
2 B         df
```

Answer (score 0):

You will never have a data.frame as you try to construct with a numeric value and a character value, so most likely you start with character values. As you want to keep your "non-dates" together with your dates in the same column, those both need to be stored as character strings. So try to make it a number and if that does not result in NA you can make it a date which you  need to convert to a character string again.

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B"), b = c("19080", "df"), stringsAsFactors = F)

asd %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(b)), as.character(as.Date(as.numeric(b), origin = "1970-01-01")), b))

#     a     b    
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     19080
# 2 B     df
```

Comment: I got your point. Looks like its is tricky. What if we have ````data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "C"), b = c("19080", "df", "4"), stringsAsFactors = F)````  We just have to covert only 19080 to date??

Comment: it will always be tricky to store different type of data in the same column, you know your data best of course. You can chose to only convert the number to a date if bigger than a certain value.